# Publish to webstore -> "The app runs only on Chrome OS"

Tags: google-chrome-app

The last two weeks I've been been writing a chrome app in order to update a microcontroller using the chrome.serial API. Now beeing almost ready with the main functionality and trying to publish the application the web store says "The app runs only on Chrome OS".

I'm afraid during development I missed the hint that chrome apps will no longer be supported. Unfortunately I can't easily port it to an extension or progressive web app since the app depends on the chrome.serial.* API

Does somebody know how to publish the app for Windows/Mac/Linux anyhow?
Or maybe how to port to a native app using the chrome.serial api?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can continue using the same Chrome App codebase with NW.js, but you will need to distribute to those platforms another way.

https://nwjs.io/blog/chrome-apps-support/

https://nwjs.io/blog/whats-new-in-0.13/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I meanwhile figured out nw.js runs my application out of the box which is great. Now I'm struggeling with how to create executables for different platforms.